# Is there a way to make consistent result out of split function?(same amounts of words)

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, split

I am working on search function and I am splitting search query into separated words. I know that there will be no more than 10 words, but there might be less.

Since I need to make SQL query, with consistent amount of words, let's say 10, I need to add 8 more blank words in case user typed only 2.

Is there any smart way how to do it or should I just make a loop from 1 to 10 and check if that particular position is null, if yes then fill it with blank word?

SQL query would look something like this(but with 9 ANDs):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column1 LIKE '%word1%'
AND column1 LIKE '%word2%'
AND column1 LIKE '%word3%'
```

Basically what I want to do is this, but maybe in some smarter way:

```
    String[] finalSearch = new String[10];
    String[] search=searchInput.split(" ", -1);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        if (search[i]!=null){
            finalSearch[i] = search[i];
        }else{
            finalSearch[i]="";
        }
    }
```

Comment: How your SQL query looks like?

Comment: `Since I need to make SQL query, with consistent amount of words` - Is this mandatory ? Can't you just send 2 parameters in SQL query if the user enters only 2 words ?

Comment: Is it `AND` or `OR` in your SQL query ? Do you always search the same column ? If `column1` matches `word1`, do you you still need to search in the same `column1` for `word2` ?

Comment: `AND` and `OR` are in SQL query and it could be just 2 parameters, but what if user types 9 words? I need to check also them... and yes it is checking one single column which contains a sentence.

Comment: I still feel that there's something wrong with your SQL query :) Looks it returns only the row when a sentence has all the words being searched.. is that your intent ?

Comment: Yes it is, it serves for auto-completion, so if user types, every keystroke is one call of the function. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate query depends on user input like this:

```
static String getQuery(String ... userInput){
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM mytable");
        if (userInput.length>0){
            sb.append(" where");
            for (int i=0;i<userInput.length;i++){
                sb.append(" column1 LIKE '%"+userInput[i]+"%'");
                if (i!=userInput.length-1) sb.append(" AND");
            }
        }
        sb.append(";");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Much better solution than mine, I feel so dumb now... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a list with the *terms* you want to search for:

```
// List<String> terms
StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM mytable ");

if (terms.isEmpty()) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("SOME DESCRIPTION HERE") }
sqlQuery.append("WHERE column1 LIKE ? ");
for (int i = 1; i < terms.length(), i++) {
  sqlQuery.append("AND column1 LIKE ? ");
}

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
Connection connection = null;

try {
  // Get your JDBC connection as usual
  // connection = getJdbcConnection();
  preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery.toString());

  for (int i = 0; i < terms.length(), i++) {
    preparedStatement.setString(i + 1, "%" + terms[i] + "%");
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // Do something here with he exception
} finally {
  // Make sure you close JDBC resources here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a fixed number of words (10) could you have it build the query with only the words you need?

Could you do something like this:

```
String [] words = search.split ();
query = "SELECT * FROM my table WHERE";
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
   query += "columns LIKE " + words[i];
   If (i < words.length - 1)
      query += "AND";
}
```